# Why Git fails to ignore the folder I've put in gitignore file?

Tags: git

In my `.gitignore` file, I just have gulp. Yet after `git ls-tree -r dev --name-only` reveals that it still tracks that folder. Why?

I tried to write `/gulp` instead of `gulp`, to no avail.

[image: FILES]

[image: .GITIGNORE]

Comment: A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. **Files already tracked by Git are not affected.** [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Commit all your changes**

Before proceeding, make sure all your changes are committed, including your .gitignore file.

**Step 2: Remove everything from the repository**

To clear your repo, use:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

`rm` is the remove command

`-r` will allow recursive removal

`–cached` will only remove files from the index.

Your files will still be there but the rm command can be unforgiving. If you wish to try what it does beforehand, add the -n or --dry-run flag to test things out.

**Step 3: Re add everything**

```
git add .
```

**Step 4: Commit**

```
git commit -m ".gitignore fix"
```